# How to sort a list of lines based on an nth column?

Tags: python, sorting

In python I can sort a list like this...

```
lines = ["C: fish house bridge chocolate",
         "C: hamster pen flower penny",
         "C: dog park car paper",
         "C: hamster pen bus tank",
         "C: hamster lolly stick shirt"]

lines = sorted(lines)
for line in lines:
    print (line)
```

Gives...

```
C: dog park car paper
C: fish house bridge chocolate
C: hamster lolly stick shirt
C: hamster pen bus tank
C: hamster pen flower penny
```

I can also sort by a particular column...

```
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line.split()[1])
for line in lines:
    print (line)
```

Gives...

```
C: dog park car paper
C: fish house bridge chocolate
C: hamster pen flower penny
C: hamster pen bus tank
C: hamster lolly stick shirt
```

How can I remove lines so that the combined 2nd and 3rd columns of each line are unique?

Desired output would be...

```
C: dog park car paper
C: fish house bridge chocolate
C: hamster pen bus tank
C: hamster lolly stick shirt
```

In awk I could use something like !seen...

```
awk '!seen[$1][$2][$3]++'
```

What about in python?

Comment: What does this have to do with sorting? It seems like you want to sort *then* remove duplicates, no?

Comment: Sounds like you want to know how to sort the lines by some combed columns. Correct?

Comment: I mean, I need the 2nd plus 3rd columns to be unique. They are treated like 1 column for the purpose of uniqueness. I have no idea how to do this so I cant make an honest attempt.

Comment: Related: [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7961363/4518341)

Comment: Why is `hamster pen` before `hamster lolly` in your desired output? They sort in the opposite order.

Answer (score 3):

I would propose the following solution:

```
lines = ["C: fish house bridge chocolate",
"C: hamster pen flower penny",
"C: dog park car paper",
"C: hamster pen bus tank",
"C: hamster lolly stick shirt"]

lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda line: line.split()[1])
seen = set()
for line in lines:
    key = tuple(line.split()[1:3])
    if key not in seen:
        print(line)
        seen.add(key)
```

This prints

```
C: dog park car paper
C: fish house bridge chocolate
C: hamster pen flower penny
C: hamster lolly stick shirt
```

The combined 2nd and 3rd columns of each line are unique but it differs from your desired output because the first unique line is kept.

Comment: Note that if you do `lines = sorted(lines)`, the right lines are there in the output, but 3 and 4 are out of order compared to OP, which makes more sense IMO.

Comment: Thank you. While I am not using this solution, it inspired my own. ```seen = []
for line in lines:
    2 = line.split()[1]
    3 = line.split()[2]
    check = (2) + " " + (3)
    if check not in seen:
        print (check)
        seen.append(check)```

Comment: @Chris Please post that as an answer. Code formatting in comments is neutered by design. (And yes, you can answer your own question. ️ )

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of dictionary keys and use them to handle grouping your lines together.

```py
lines = ["C: fish house bridge chocolate",
         "C: hamster pen flower penny",
         "C: dog park car paper",
         "C: hamster pen bus tank",
         "C: hamster lolly stick shirt"]

d = {''.join(line.split()[2:3]): line for line in sorted(lines, key=lambda v: v.split()[1])}
for line in d.values():
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
C: dog park car paper
C: fish house bridge chocolate
C: hamster pen bus tank
C: hamster lolly stick shirt
```

Comment: Note that dicts are only guaranteed to preserve order [in Python 3.7+ and CPython 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @wuerfelfreak I decided to do it like this...

```
seen = []
for line in lines:
    a = line.split()[1]
    b = line.split()[2]
    check = (a) + " " + (b)
    if check not in seen:
        print (line)
        seen.append(check)
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as @wuerfelfreak's solution except using a list, which is less performant, i.e. O(n) lookups vs O(1) using a set.

Comment: I got a different output after fixing the variable names. Is `lines` supposed to be sorted first?